# Maven Release Plugin with Svn:Externals and a multi-module project

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-release-plugin

Given the following sample multi-module project:

- aggr/pom.xml        (Version 1.0-SNAPSHOT)
- aggr/parent/pom.xml (Version 2.0-SNAPSHOT)
- aggr/app/pom.xml    (Version 3.0-SNAPSHOT)
- aggr/comp1/pom.xml  (Version 4.0-SNAPSHOT)

where parent is the parent of any other pom and app has a dependency of comp1.

Releasing via release:prepare/perform **just works fine** as long as the aggr folder has the same structure within the svn repository (repository/trunk/aggr/parent.pom, ...).

Now when I want to use the same project but with svn:externals, the release-plugin doesn't work stating that comp1:

`Can't release project due to non released dependencies : parent:pom:2.0-SNAPSHOT`

The repository structure is then something like

- repository/aggr/trunk/pom.xml
- repository/parent/trunk/pom.xml
- repository/app/trunk/pom.xml
- repository/comp1/trunk/pom.xml

the aggr folder uses externals pointing to the module-trunks and therefore the checked out working copy looks like the above.

Why is Maven handling modules based on externals differently and is there a way to overcome this?

Edit: The pom-Files of the svn:externals Project. The only difference to the pom-Files of the other project are the scm tags. In the other non-externals project only the aggregator has the scm tag.

External parent-pom.xml

```
<groupId>small.test</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://localhost/svn/small-test-ext/parent/trunk/</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://localhost/svn/small-test-ext/parent/trunk/</developerConnection>
    <url>http://localhost/svn/small-test-ext/parent/trunk/</url>
</scm>

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

External aggr-pom.xml
    
        small.test
        parent
        2.0-SNAPSHOT

```
<groupId>small.test</groupId>
<artifactId>aggr</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://localhost/svn/small-test-ext/aggr/trunk/</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://localhost/svn/small-test-ext/aggr/trunk/</developerConnection>
    <url>http://localhost/svn/small-test-ext/aggr/trunk/</url>
</scm>

<modules>
    <module>parent</module>
    <module>comp1</module>
    <module>comp2</module>
    <module>app</module>
</modules>
```

External app-pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>small.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<groupId>small.test</groupId>
<version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://localhost/svn/small-test-ext/app/trunk/</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://localhost/svn/small-test-ext/app/trunk/</developerConnection>
    <url>http://localhost/svn/small-test-ext/app/trunk/</url>
</scm>

<dependencies>  
    <dependency>
    <groupId>small.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>comp1</artifactId>
    <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks
Konrad

Comment: The main problem you have is not using the same version for all modules etc. Furthermore can you show the pom files ? Apart from that why are you using externals to create a multi-module structure and not creating a real one without externals?

Comment: The modules and the parent of the real project are being used in several projects. Therefore I have to rely on externals and cannot use the same version for the whole project.

Comment: That's not really a reason, cause if you have a multi-module build you can use the modules separately. So if you don't change the folder structure into a single SVN tree instead of using externals you won't get running it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current project you must run `mvn:release` for each one, cause you have projects or modules in different svn repositories. If you want to run just one `mvn:release` your repository should looks like:

```
svn_repository: branches/
            tags/
            trunk/
                  parent
                  comp1
                  comp2
                  app
                  pom.xml
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. Thanks! Do you know if there exists a plugin which automatically calls release:prepare for all submodules in the right order?

Comment: In case your problem was in the pushing phase since 2.0 they added a property 'DcommitByProject' that can commit per project, so submodules works. I execute this command on root and submodules works fine
    mvn release:prepare -DcommitByProject=true