# Maven Eclipse SVN integration in a large project

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn

I started working recently on a quite big Java project divided into separate libraries. These are maintained as a **Maven dependencies** (not multi-module project).

How can I automatize the process of building main project and its dependencies?

The ideal case would be that the **Maven build** gets invoked only in the case of encountering changes in **SVN code**. I use **Eclipse + m2e + Subclipse**, as for now I need to take care of this by hand, remembering which dependencies do I need, synchronizing for **SVN changes** and then making build manually.

Sorry if this is a complete newbie question, but I've never been working in such environment up to this moment.

Comment: Use Jenkins + Nexus  .

Comment: Seems to be a little overcomplicated solution. I meant something straightforward, to be run on demand, not continously. Maybe some Eclipse plugin with such functionality? I suppose I will gonna have to create some Python script to automatize it - but again, maybe there is some piece of code already there to support in this task?

Comment: you can create a script powershell and launch it with **Windows task Scheduler** if you use windows

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create an [aggregate POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Aggregation) and use [SVN externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) to create the correct structure.

Take into account that using externals you can "link" to the latest revision in a branch or an specific revision.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297499/maven-release-plugin-with-svnexternals-and-a-multi-module-project) you can see a sample project using externals in SVN and an aggregated pom.xml

Note: if you are using mvn:release and using externals, you should run indepently for each external.